# How to change values of flexible array inside of a struct from within a function?

Tags: c

I am trying to rewrite a bit array thingy I wrote, and one of the thing i wanted to add is a function that makes it easy to set the values in a bit array. right now, my bit array looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
  int length;
  char bitarray[];
}BitArray;
```

I am trying to write a function:

```
void initBitArray(BitArray * b, int numBits, int initVal);
```

That set length to numBits and bitarray to an array of chars that is numBits/8 + 1 long, with each char having a value initVal. The only part I am having trouble with is with setting the value of bitarray. This isn't homework or anything, I was just trying to make some hobby code prettier.
This is what I tried to do:

```
void initBitArray(BitArray * b, int numBits, int initVal){
  char foo[numBits/8 + 1]; 
  b->bitarray = foo;
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<numBits/8 + 1; ++i){
    b->bitarray[i]=val;
  }
  b->length = numBits;
  return;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work :p

I tried this:

```
void initBitArray(BitArray * b, int numBits, int initVal){
  b = (BitArray *)realloc( b, sizeof(b) + numBits/8 + 1);
  b->length = numBits;
  int i;
  for (i=0; i< (b->length); ++i){
    b->bitarray[i]=initVal;
  }
  return;
}
```

and it compiles but gives me a runtime error?

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: realloc(): invalid old size: 0xbfe573f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb76c0fd4]
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb76c4a29]
/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0x107)[0xb76c5657]
/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0x3c)[0xb76c558c]
./prog[0x8048556]
./prog[0x80483f1]
======= Memory map: ========
```

Comment: If `numBits` is 8, then `numBits/8 + 1` is 2. Is that what you really want?

Comment: yes, it makes everything simpler. one extra byte is not that bad :p

Comment: you could make `char* bitarray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BitArray *allocBitArray(int length)
{
    BitArray *ba = malloc(sizeof(BitArray) + length);
    if (ba != 0)
    {
        ba->length = length;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
             ba->bitarray[i] = 0;
    }
    return ba;
}
```

You could do the loop other ways — for example, by using `memset()`, or by using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.  Note that unlike the 'struct hack' in pre-C99 days, the flexible array member mechanism allows you to allocate exactly the space you need and no more — reliably and portably.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a struct with a flexible array member can only be allocated dynamically (i.e. with the *alloc family of functions). Thus, to resize the `bitarray[]` member, you'd call `realloc` on your BitArray pointer with a new size of `sizeof(BitArray) + flexible_member_size_you_want`.

Flexible members are accessed like all the others, i.e.

```
BitArray *b = /* ... */;
b->length = /* ... */;
b->bitarray[0] = /* ... */;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the *alloc functions. I've never used a flexible array before. could you show an example?